# Format in edittext 00:00

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In Android Studio I would like to have a Edittext that uses the format `00:00` and where you don't have to type the `:` in `00:00` . Is there a way this can be done in the layout or should this be done programmaticly?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you type the :? Would it work if you tried to use the ascii value for :

Comment: I can type it but for the end user it would be easier not to :)

Comment: I'm almost sure only way to do this is programmatically.

Comment: You can receive callbacks as a user changes the text by adding a TextWatcher to the edit text `TextView.addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)`

Answer (score -1):

If you're open to use an external library, I would recommend to search for one of the many MaskedEditTexts libraries. I've used [edittext-mask](https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask) in one of my projects and it's quite straight forward:

1st- add it to your proyect:

```
compile 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'
```

2nd- use MaskedEditText instead of regular Android's EditText:

```
<br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
    android:id="@+id/phone_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    mask:allowed_chars="1234567890"
    mask:mask="##:###"
    android:hint="12:34"
    app:keep_hint="true"
/>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

do this in xml

```
<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/editText"   
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:maxLength="5" />
```

And in Add `addTextChangedListener` to edittext

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
     {

     }

     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
     {

     }

     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
     {
          String text = editText.getText().toString();
          textlength = editText.getText().length();

          if(textlength == 2)
          {
           editText.setText(text + ":");
          }
      }
  });
```

This will work for you.